# How can I fix a ceiling fan that is trying to spin both ways?

Tags: fans

Just installed a ceiling fan. Light works fine and I have power to the fan. The problem is that the fan will try to turn clockwise for a second and then counter clockwise and then back again. I can spin the fan by hand in either direction, then it will operate normally. It is wired to a single switch and operates by remote control. I have also tried the direction button on the remote while it is turning but to no avail. Is there a switch inside the fan that could be wired wrong? Please advise.

Comment: Dying/dead capacitor? AC Motors of this sort are generally biased to start in one direction ot the other by a minor adjustment in the phase of their coils relative to each other. The circuit which does that uses a capacitor to get the slight delay. Caps can fail, over time. Not sure so making this comment rather than answer,  but...

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are a few reasons for this but this happened to me years ago and simply the switch (usually black horizontal on/off style) was in the middle.  Turn it to the left or right.  I know that you have a remote that should change this but I wonder if it would work while in the middle position.